# Getting started with hammer.js on Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, hammer.js

I am having trouble enabling touch events with Meteor. I installed `chriswessels:hammer`package but for some reason it's not working. I am probably missing something very simple. Do I need to somehow initialize it?

When I simply add

```
Template.showProduct.gestures({
 'swipe': function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("HAMMERTIME!");
  }
});
```

Nothing happens. Here is a code sample http://meteorpad.com/pad/ZStmQwaPfP9LNDX2v/Hammertime

I changed

```
Template.player.events({
  'click': function () {
    Session.set("selectedPlayer", this._id);
  }
});
```

to

```
Template.player.events({
  'tap': function () {
    Session.set("selectedPlayer", this._id);
  }
});
```

Shouldn't that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welly you are missing the CSS Selector.

> The object keys should follow the format gestureName cssSelector and
>   the value should be a callback function that is executed when the
>   specified gesture is performed on the element(s) matching the CSS
>   selector.

So change the code to this.

```
Template.showProduct.gestures({
 'swipe .myItem': function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("HAMMERTIME!");
  }
});
```

Where `myItem` should be a panel or whatever you want to swipe.

Comment: I already tried e.g. `'swipe body'` but nothing changes. I also tried with css classes etc. Please look at this http://meteorpad.com/pad/ZStmQwaPfP9LNDX2v/Hammertime
`/client/app.js` and line 26 onward.

Comment: it works for me, on the meteor pad it dosnt work idk why, but i made a simple repo on my pc with `swipe left` and it works, you should know that you need to replace `events` to `gestures` and `'tap'` should have a css selector

Comment: Great!  Thank you @Ethaan I got it working on my computer as well. For some reason it's not working on Meteorpad.